# with or without & for calling Synchronize() in C++ builder

Tags: c++builder

My Environment:

OS - Windows7 Pro(32bit)

IDE - RadStudio XE2 Update4

I am wondering about Synchronize() function.

The Synchronize() function is used in the thread program. About using the Synchronize() in C+ builder, the example is as follows ( as can be seen in [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Defining_Thread_Objects))

```
//   Important: Methods and properties of objects in VCL can only be
//   used in a method called using Synchronize, for example:
//
//      Synchronize(&UpdateCaption);
//
//   where UpdateCaption could look like:
//
//      void __fastcall TMyThreadClass::UpdateCaption()
//      {
//        Form1->Caption = "Updated in a thread";
//      }
```

What I am confused is that , in some older version of C++ builder (e.g. bcb6),
the Synchronize() was used

```
// Synchronize(UpdateCaption);
```

without "&" before the function name;

Also in the delphi code as in [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Defining_Thread_Objects),
there is no "&" before the function name;

```
// Synchronize(UpdateCaption);
```

So, which is the correct way to use Synchronize() in C++ builder

```
// Synchronize(UpdateCaption);
```

or

```
// Synchronize(&UpdateCaption);
```

I tried both in the actual code, but seems identical in the working manner.
Do both UpdateCaption and &UpdateCaption return address of functions?

Comment: in Standard C++, `UpdateCaption` and `&UpdateCaption` are illegal. It's a C++Builder extension that, for a member function, `&UpdateCaption` evaluates to a `__closure`, which is a pointer to the combination of an object and a member function on that object.   (C++11 added closures to the language; however C++Builder predates that by a long way, so they had to add their own extension for it).  Apparently there is also a feature that `UpdateCaption` implicitly converts to `&UpdateCaption` in  overload resolution, although it doesn't do so on its own! (e.g. `UpdateCaption;` gives an error).

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thank you for your comment. So this is extention by C++ Builder not the standard C++.

Comment: Yes - standard C++ (before C++11) does not have closures ; the only functions you can take the address of are non-member functions.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: That is not true. Standard C++ has had Member Function Pointers for years, so you can take the address of a member function. It is just very limited in use. `Synchronize()` (and events) specifically rely on Borland's `__closure` extension, which is much more flexible than a MFP. A MFP is specific to a particular class.  A closure is not, which makes it possible to assign different classes to the same pointer-to-member variable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I mean that `&FunctionName` does not work in Standard C++. To get a MFP you have to write `&ClassName::FunctionName`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: agreed in that regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, which is the correct way to use Synchronize() in C++ builder
>
> // Synchronize(UpdateCaption);
>
> or
>
> // Synchronize(&UpdateCaption);

They both work, but `&` is preferred.

> Do both UpdateCaption and &UpdateCaption return address of functions?

Yes.  If you refer to a function/method without specifying parenthesis for the parameter list, the address of the function/method is assumed.  The `&` just makes it more explicit.

Comment: for a member function, `f;` gives an error but `&f;` does not, so it is not quite that simple. It appears that `f` is only converted to `&f` in certain contexts (one of them, at least, being when used as a function argument).

Comment: although it's not clear in that example wherther `UpdateCaption` is a member function or not (if it isn't then it could be made static, since it does not actually use `this`)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `Synchronize()` requires a member method (or an anonymous procedure in modern versions, but those are difficult to use in C++). The difference between `Synchronize(UpdateCaption)` and `Synchronize(&UpdateCaption)` depends on compile version. As the OP said, both work in BCB6, but that was changed in a later version so that users should always use `Synchronize(&UpdateCaption)` only. The same rule applies when assigning event handlers in code, eg: `Comp->OnEvent = Handler;` vs `Comp->OnEvent = &Handler;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies, Remy Lebeau and MAtt McNabb. So I should use Synchronize(&UpdateCaption). @RemyLebau: Thank you also for noting about assigning event handler. I did not recognize that.